# Chart date frequencies from values that include times

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet which in a row A cells has this data. I want to create a chart which plots the amount of times an event occurs on a date e.g. 30/7/14. Do I need to first remove the 11:13, and then create a pivot table and if so, how?

```
Event Time
30/07/14 11:13
30/07/14 11:06
30/07/14 11:05
30/07/14 11:04
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column and use the INT Function to round the Event Time down to just a date, thereby removing the hours and minutes. Then just Pivot as you normally would.

Comment: INT function with what formula?

Comment: Say one instance of the Event Time is in cell A2, just use =INT(A2). This will change from 01/01/2014 03:25 to just 01/01/2014. Repeat the same for all rows.